# member defined in anonymous struct in protected anonymous union is still publicly visible

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, unions, anonymous-inner-class

I have managed to compile and run **c++** code even though it shouldn't.

The following snippet should not compile:

```
template<typename T, size_t SIZE>
struct Vector {
    Vector(std::initializer_list<T> data) {
        std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), this->data);
    }

    Vector(T(&data)[SIZE]) {
        std::copy(data, data + SIZE, this->data);
    }

protected:
#pragma pack(push, 1) //stores the alignment of aggregate types and sets it to 1 byte
    union {
        struct {
            T x, y, z, w;
        };
        T data[SIZE];
    };
#pragma pack(pop) //restore old data alignment
};

template<typename T>
struct Vector2 : public Vector<T, 2> {
    using Vector<T, 2>::Vector<T, 2>;

    Vector2(T x = 0, T y = 0) :
        Vector({ x, y }){}

    Vector2(const Vector& vec) :
        Vector(vec) {}

    using Vector::x;
    using Vector::y;
};

int main() {
    double floats[2]{ 2, 3 };
    Vector2<double> v{ floats };
    Vector<double, 2> c{ 5., 6. };

    std::cout << "v.x = " << v.x;
    //Is oke, v.x is visible here because of the public using statement

    std::cout << " c.x = " << c.x << "\n";
    //Is not oke, c is not a Vector2<double>. It is a Vector<double, 2> so its member x is protected and thus not visible from here.
}
```

**output:** `v.x = 2 c.x = 5`

So this program does not only successfully compile and link but it also runs and prints sensible data.
I tried changing the type of `c` to `Vector<double, 3>` but that didn't change anything. Also, members `z` and `w` are visible as well just like `x` and `y` are. However, `data` is not visible (e.g. `std::cout << c.data[0];` won't compile as expected).

Intellisense is smarter than the compiler in this case as it successfully detects the error and complains about it.

I am using **Visual studio 2013**.

**PS:**

Side question: I found another quirk of the compiler in this same code snippet. If I change the following line:

```
using Vector<T, 2>::Vector<T, 2>;
```

to:

```
using Vector<T, 2>::Vector;
```

I get this compiler error: `error C2886: 'Vector<T,0x02>' : symbol cannot be used in a member using-declaration`

If I change it to:

```
using Vector::Vector;
```

The compiler crashes all together with: `fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler. see reference to class template instantiation 'Vector2<T>' being compiled`.

This (e.g. the fact that it crashes) is probably just a bug in the compiler but, if anyone knows, I still would like to know why neither of the two alternate forms of that line compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to make some changes to get the code to compile at all on clang. It seems that visual c++ is extremely permissive and allows illegal (or should I say non-standard) syntax.

Here is the corrected program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T, size_t SIZE>
struct Vector {
    Vector(std::initializer_list<T> data) {
        std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), this->data);
    }

    Vector(T(&data)[SIZE]) {
        std::copy(data, data + SIZE, this->data);
    }

protected:
#pragma pack(push, 1) //stores the alignment of aggregate types and sets it to 1 byte
    union {
        struct {
            T x, y, z, w;
        };
        T data[SIZE];
    };
#pragma pack(pop) //restore old data alignment
};

template<typename T>
struct Vector2 : public Vector<T, 2> {
    using Vector<T, 2>::Vector;

    Vector2(T x = 0, T y = 0) :
    Vector<T, 2>({ x, y }){}

    Vector2(const Vector2& vec) :
    Vector<T, 2>(vec) {}

    using Vector<T, 2>::x;
    using Vector<T, 2>::y;
};

int main() {
    double floats[2]{ 2, 3 };
    Vector2<double> v{ floats };
    Vector<double, 2> c{ 5., 6. };

    std::cout << "v.x = " << v.x;
    //Is oke, v.x is visible here because of the public using statement

    std::cout << " c.x = " << c.x << "\n";
    //Is not oke, c is not a Vector2<double>. It is a Vector<double, 2> so its member x is protected and thus not visible from here.
}
```

Here is the (expected) error after modification:

```
./vec.cpp:66:33: error: 'x' is a protected member of 'Vector<double, 2>'
    std::cout << " c.x = " << c.x << "\n";
                                ^
./vec.cpp:37:15: note: declared protected here
            T x, y, z, w;
              ^
1 error generated.
```